# VASP: HS06 hybrid functional bandstructure with downsampled fock operator

Tags: vasp, band-structure, hse06

I am using vasp 6.2.0 to calculate bandstructure with HS06 hybrid functional. I have done

1. a DFT self-consistent calculation with GGA functional, on a uniform 20x20x20 grid; from this I copied the explicit list of 256 irreducible kpoints found in IBZKPT.
2. a DFT bandstructure calculation along 6 high symmetry lines with 30 points per segment, starting from the previous point; from this I copied the k-path from OUTCAR and set the weight of these 180 k-points to 0.

I concatenated these two forming KPOINTS file, where I updated the total number of k-points as the sum of the two contributions

```
Explicit k-point list
436
Reciprocal lattice
0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 1
0.05000000000000 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 8
0.10000000000000 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 8
0.15000000000000 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 8
0.20000000000000 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 8
0.25000000000000 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 8
0.30000000000000 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 8
0.35000000000000 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 8
0.40000000000000 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 8
0.45000000000000 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 8
0.50000000000000 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 4
0.05000000000000 0.05000000000000 0.00000000000000 6
0.10000000000000 0.05000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
0.25000000000000 0.05000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.30000000000000 0.05000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
0.35000000000000 0.05000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.40000000000000 0.05000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.45000000000000 0.05000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.05000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.05000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.40000000000000 0.05000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.35000000000000 0.05000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.30000000000000 0.05000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.25000000000000 0.05000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.10000000000000 0.05000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.05000000000000 0.05000000000000 0.00000000000000 12
0.10000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.00000000000000 6
0.15000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.20000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.30000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.35000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.40000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.45000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.10000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.40000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.35000000000000 0.10000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.30000000000000 0.10000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.20000000000000 0.10000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.15000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.10000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.00000000000000 12
0.15000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.00000000000000 6
0.20000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.25000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.30000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.35000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.40000000000000 0.15000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
0.45000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.15000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.40000000000000 0.15000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.35000000000000 0.15000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.30000000000000 0.15000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.25000000000000 0.15000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.20000000000000 0.15000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.15000000000000 0.15000000000000 -0.00000000000000 12
0.20000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.00000000000000 6
0.25000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.30000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.35000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.40000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.45000000000000 0.20000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.20000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.40000000000000 0.20000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.35000000000000 0.20000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.30000000000000 0.20000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.25000000000000 0.20000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.20000000000000 0.20000000000000 -0.00000000000000 12
0.25000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.00000000000000 6
0.30000000000000 0.25000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
0.35000000000000 0.25000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
0.40000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.45000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.25000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.40000000000000 0.25000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.35000000000000 0.25000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.30000000000000 0.25000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.25000000000000 0.25000000000000 -0.00000000000000 12
0.30000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.00000000000000 6
0.35000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.40000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.45000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.30000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.40000000000000 0.30000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.35000000000000 0.30000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.30000000000000 0.30000000000000 -0.00000000000000 12
0.35000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.00000000000000 6
0.40000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.45000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.35000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.40000000000000 0.35000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.35000000000000 0.35000000000000 -0.00000000000000 12
0.40000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.00000000000000 6
0.45000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.40000000000000 -0.00000000000000 24
-0.40000000000000 0.40000000000000 -0.00000000000000 12
0.45000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.00000000000000 6
0.50000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.00000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.45000000000000 -0.00000000000000 12
0.50000000000000 0.50000000000000 0.00000000000000 3
0.15000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.20000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.30000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.35000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.40000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.45000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.50000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.45000000000000 0.10000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.20000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.25000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.30000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.35000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.40000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.45000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.50000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.45000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.30000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.25000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.20000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.15000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.10000000000000 0.15000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.25000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.30000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.35000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.40000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.45000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.50000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.45000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.30000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.25000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.20000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.15000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.30000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.35000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.40000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.45000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.50000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.45000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.30000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.25000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.20000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.35000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.40000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.45000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.50000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.45000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.30000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.25000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.40000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.45000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
0.50000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.45000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.30000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.45000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.45000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.05000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.05000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.50000000000000 0.05000000000000 12
0.30000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.10000000000000 24
0.35000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
0.40000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
0.45000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
0.50000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.45000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.20000000000000 0.10000000000000 24
0.35000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 24
0.40000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
0.45000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
0.50000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.45000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.30000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.25000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.20000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.15000000000000 0.25000000000000 0.10000000000000 24
0.40000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.10000000000000 24
0.45000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
0.50000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.45000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.30000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.25000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.20000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.10000000000000 24
0.45000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.10000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.45000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.30000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.25000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.10000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.10000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.30000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.10000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.10000000000000 24
-0.40000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.10000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.10000000000000 24
-0.40000000000000 0.50000000000000 0.10000000000000 12
0.45000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.15000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.15000000000000 48
-0.45000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.15000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.15000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.30000000000000 0.15000000000000 24
0.50000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.15000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.15000000000000 48
-0.40000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.15000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.15000000000000 48
-0.30000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.15000000000000 48
-0.25000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.15000000000000 48
-0.20000000000000 0.35000000000000 0.15000000000000 24
-0.45000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.15000000000000 24
-0.40000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.15000000000000 48
-0.35000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.15000000000000 48
-0.30000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.15000000000000 48
-0.25000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.15000000000000 24
-0.40000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.15000000000000 24
-0.35000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.15000000000000 48
-0.30000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.15000000000000 24
-0.35000000000000 0.50000000000000 0.15000000000000 12
-0.40000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.20000000000000 24
-0.35000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.20000000000000 48
-0.30000000000000 0.40000000000000 0.20000000000000 24
-0.35000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.20000000000000 24
-0.30000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.20000000000000 48
-0.25000000000000 0.45000000000000 0.20000000000000 24
-0.30000000000000 0.50000000000000 0.20000000000000 12
-0.25000000000000 0.50000000000000 0.25000000000000 6
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0
0.01724138 0.00000000 0.01724138 0
0.03448276 0.00000000 0.03448276 0
0.05172414 0.00000000 0.05172414 0
0.06896552 0.00000000 0.06896552 0
0.08620690 0.00000000 0.08620690 0
0.10344828 0.00000000 0.10344828 0
0.12068966 0.00000000 0.12068966 0
0.13793103 0.00000000 0.13793103 0
0.15517241 0.00000000 0.15517241 0
0.17241379 0.00000000 0.17241379 0
0.18965517 0.00000000 0.18965517 0
0.20689655 0.00000000 0.20689655 0
0.22413793 0.00000000 0.22413793 0
0.24137931 0.00000000 0.24137931 0
0.25862069 0.00000000 0.25862069 0
0.27586207 0.00000000 0.27586207 0
0.29310345 0.00000000 0.29310345 0
0.31034483 0.00000000 0.31034483 0
0.32758621 0.00000000 0.32758621 0
0.34482759 0.00000000 0.34482759 0
0.36206897 0.00000000 0.36206897 0
0.37931034 0.00000000 0.37931034 0
0.39655172 0.00000000 0.39655172 0
0.41379310 0.00000000 0.41379310 0
0.43103448 0.00000000 0.43103448 0
0.44827586 0.00000000 0.44827586 0
0.46551724 0.00000000 0.46551724 0
0.48275862 0.00000000 0.48275862 0
0.50000000 0.00000000 0.50000000 0
0.50000000 0.00000000 0.50000000 0
0.50431034 0.00862069 0.50431034 0
0.50862069 0.01724138 0.50862069 0
0.51293103 0.02586207 0.51293103 0
0.51724138 0.03448276 0.51724138 0
0.52155172 0.04310345 0.52155172 0
0.52586207 0.05172414 0.52586207 0
0.53017241 0.06034483 0.53017241 0
0.53448276 0.06896552 0.53448276 0
0.53879310 0.07758621 0.53879310 0
0.54310345 0.08620690 0.54310345 0
0.54741379 0.09482759 0.54741379 0
0.55172414 0.10344828 0.55172414 0
0.55603448 0.11206897 0.55603448 0
0.56034483 0.12068966 0.56034483 0
0.56465517 0.12931034 0.56465517 0
0.56896552 0.13793103 0.56896552 0
0.57327586 0.14655172 0.57327586 0
0.57758621 0.15517241 0.57758621 0
0.58189655 0.16379310 0.58189655 0
0.58620690 0.17241379 0.58620690 0
0.59051724 0.18103448 0.59051724 0
0.59482759 0.18965517 0.59482759 0
0.59913793 0.19827586 0.59913793 0
0.60344828 0.20689655 0.60344828 0
0.60775862 0.21551724 0.60775862 0
0.61206897 0.22413793 0.61206897 0
0.61637931 0.23275862 0.61637931 0
0.62068966 0.24137931 0.62068966 0
0.62500000 0.25000000 0.62500000 0
0.37500000 0.37500000 0.75000000 0
0.36206897 0.36206897 0.72413793 0
0.34913793 0.34913793 0.69827586 0
0.33620690 0.33620690 0.67241379 0
0.32327586 0.32327586 0.64655172 0
0.31034483 0.31034483 0.62068966 0
0.29741379 0.29741379 0.59482759 0
0.28448276 0.28448276 0.56896552 0
0.27155172 0.27155172 0.54310345 0
0.25862069 0.25862069 0.51724138 0
0.24568966 0.24568966 0.49137931 0
0.23275862 0.23275862 0.46551724 0
0.21982759 0.21982759 0.43965517 0
0.20689655 0.20689655 0.41379310 0
0.19396552 0.19396552 0.38793103 0
0.18103448 0.18103448 0.36206897 0
0.16810345 0.16810345 0.33620690 0
0.15517241 0.15517241 0.31034483 0
0.14224138 0.14224138 0.28448276 0
0.12931034 0.12931034 0.25862069 0
0.11637931 0.11637931 0.23275862 0
0.10344828 0.10344828 0.20689655 0
0.09051724 0.09051724 0.18103448 0
0.07758621 0.07758621 0.15517241 0
0.06465517 0.06465517 0.12931034 0
0.05172414 0.05172414 0.10344828 0
0.03879310 0.03879310 0.07758621 0
0.02586207 0.02586207 0.05172414 0
0.01293103 0.01293103 0.02586207 0
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0
0.01724138 0.01724138 0.01724138 0
0.03448276 0.03448276 0.03448276 0
0.05172414 0.05172414 0.05172414 0
0.06896552 0.06896552 0.06896552 0
0.08620690 0.08620690 0.08620690 0
0.10344828 0.10344828 0.10344828 0
0.12068966 0.12068966 0.12068966 0
0.13793103 0.13793103 0.13793103 0
0.15517241 0.15517241 0.15517241 0
0.17241379 0.17241379 0.17241379 0
0.18965517 0.18965517 0.18965517 0
0.20689655 0.20689655 0.20689655 0
0.22413793 0.22413793 0.22413793 0
0.24137931 0.24137931 0.24137931 0
0.25862069 0.25862069 0.25862069 0
0.27586207 0.27586207 0.27586207 0
0.29310345 0.29310345 0.29310345 0
0.31034483 0.31034483 0.31034483 0
0.32758621 0.32758621 0.32758621 0
0.34482759 0.34482759 0.34482759 0
0.36206897 0.36206897 0.36206897 0
0.37931034 0.37931034 0.37931034 0
0.39655172 0.39655172 0.39655172 0
0.41379310 0.41379310 0.41379310 0
0.43103448 0.43103448 0.43103448 0
0.44827586 0.44827586 0.44827586 0
0.46551724 0.46551724 0.46551724 0
0.48275862 0.48275862 0.48275862 0
0.50000000 0.50000000 0.50000000 0
0.50000000 0.50000000 0.50000000 0
0.50000000 0.49137931 0.50862069 0
0.50000000 0.48275862 0.51724138 0
0.50000000 0.47413793 0.52586207 0
0.50000000 0.46551724 0.53448276 0
0.50000000 0.45689655 0.54310345 0
0.50000000 0.44827586 0.55172414 0
0.50000000 0.43965517 0.56034483 0
0.50000000 0.43103448 0.56896552 0
0.50000000 0.42241379 0.57758621 0
0.50000000 0.41379310 0.58620690 0
0.50000000 0.40517241 0.59482759 0
0.50000000 0.39655172 0.60344828 0
0.50000000 0.38793103 0.61206897 0
0.50000000 0.37931034 0.62068966 0
0.50000000 0.37068966 0.62931034 0
0.50000000 0.36206897 0.63793103 0
0.50000000 0.35344828 0.64655172 0
0.50000000 0.34482759 0.65517241 0
0.50000000 0.33620690 0.66379310 0
0.50000000 0.32758621 0.67241379 0
0.50000000 0.31896552 0.68103448 0
0.50000000 0.31034483 0.68965517 0
0.50000000 0.30172414 0.69827586 0
0.50000000 0.29310345 0.70689655 0
0.50000000 0.28448276 0.71551724 0
0.50000000 0.27586207 0.72413793 0
0.50000000 0.26724138 0.73275862 0
0.50000000 0.25862069 0.74137931 0
0.50000000 0.25000000 0.75000000 0
0.50000000 0.25000000 0.75000000 0
0.50000000 0.24137931 0.74137931 0
0.50000000 0.23275862 0.73275862 0
0.50000000 0.22413793 0.72413793 0
0.50000000 0.21551724 0.71551724 0
0.50000000 0.20689655 0.70689655 0
0.50000000 0.19827586 0.69827586 0
0.50000000 0.18965517 0.68965517 0
0.50000000 0.18103448 0.68103448 0
0.50000000 0.17241379 0.67241379 0
0.50000000 0.16379310 0.66379310 0
0.50000000 0.15517241 0.65517241 0
0.50000000 0.14655172 0.64655172 0
0.50000000 0.13793103 0.63793103 0
0.50000000 0.12931034 0.62931034 0
0.50000000 0.12068966 0.62068966 0
0.50000000 0.11206897 0.61206897 0
0.50000000 0.10344828 0.60344828 0
0.50000000 0.09482759 0.59482759 0
0.50000000 0.08620690 0.58620690 0
0.50000000 0.07758621 0.57758621 0
0.50000000 0.06896552 0.56896552 0
0.50000000 0.06034483 0.56034483 0
0.50000000 0.05172414 0.55172414 0
0.50000000 0.04310345 0.54310345 0
0.50000000 0.03448276 0.53448276 0
0.50000000 0.02586207 0.52586207 0
0.50000000 0.01724138 0.51724138 0
0.50000000 0.00862069 0.50862069 0
0.50000000 0.00000000 0.50000000 0
```

I used the following INCAR file:

```
## Selects the HSE06 hybrid functional
LHFCALC = .TRUE. ; HFSCREEN = 0.2 ; 
ALGO = NORMAL 
LFOCKACE = .TRUE.
ISTART=1
ISMEAR =  0
SIGMA  =  0.01
GGA    = PE
NCORE = 2 up to number-of-cores-per-socket (or number-of-cores-per-node)
NKRED = 4
KPAR=4
NWRITE = 4
```

However I got an error about using the wrong number of k-points

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                     _     ____    _    _    _____     _                     |
|                    | |   |  _ \  | |  | |  / ____|   | |                    |
|                    | |   | |_) | | |  | | | |  __    | |                    |
|                    |_|   |  _ <  | |  | | | | |_ |   |_|                    |
|                     _    | |_) | | |__| | | |__| |    _                     |
|                    (_)   |____/   \____/   \_____|   (_)                    |
|                                                                             |
|     internal error in: fock_dbl.F  at line: 1502                            |
|                                                                             |
|     internal error in FOCK_FCC: number of k-points incorrect 5715 8000      |
|     4 4 4                                                                   |
|                                                                             |
|     If you are not a developer, you should not encounter this problem.      |
|     Please submit a bug report.                                             |
|                                                                             |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I think it might be because I'm using NKRED=4 to downsample the number of q-points to 5x5x5, out of a 20x20x20 k-points grid. If this is the case, how can I get the right k-points file which accounts for the downsampling?

Comment: +1. Does this mean that you've succeeded in installing [VASP with HDF5](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10236/5)?

Comment: No, I am using a pre-existing installation of vasp 6.2.0 without HDF5 :)

Comment: Can you update us now that it has been 10+ months since you asked this question? Have you found the answer? Are you still actively in need of an answer?